# MVC FormsAuthentication not working after user logged in

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a login method that succsfully communicates with my DB and sets the authCookie in 4.5.1.

```
 [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
    {

//call my DB
 FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I then redirect to an index page decorated With the [Authorize]
and it works as expected.

On this page i have an HttPost method that gets called from Jquery/Ajax:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RemovePermission(string staff)
    {

       if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            DataAccessor d = new DataAccessor();
            d.Remove(staff);

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

if i decorate this method with [Authorize], it does not work(never steps into the method, presumably because it does not think the user is logged in.). If i dont and check if the user is authenticated in the above if statement, they are not.

//Web.Config
    forms loginUrl="~/Home/LogIn" timeout="1000"

What am i missing?

Comment: What happens if you create your persistent cookie? ie: setting your boolean to true in the method call. `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, true);`

Comment: If the error code your getting on RemovePermission method is 401, so yes, then you can be sure it's a permission problem

Comment: I tried with the true, same issue. This one is baffling me. From what i have read about the FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie . It only decorates the next http request with the authenticated information and nothing past that. I cant believe thats the case but that appears to be whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the below, try removing it from the modules in your web.config:

```
<remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i created an empty MVC project and do not have the line or an <httpModules> section in the web.config.